# Janusgraph how to deal with the global_offline misconfiguration

Tags: graph-databases, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

when i tired to remove an index, I typed wrong **GLOBAL_OFFLINE** setting in **userConfig** in the **ManagementSystem**, which I mistake typed the "index.search.backend" with a directory string ......

when i try to open this janusgraph, the print out as below :

```
WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration  
       Local setting index.search.backend=lucene (Type: GLOBAL_OFFLINE) is overridden by globally managed value (/data/lucene).  Use the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control this setting.
INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Configuring index [search]    
       Could not find implementation class: /data/lucene
```

I wonder whether i could **not drop this table** at the backend and fix this problem !
**many thx !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have fix this problem !
I just use the **KCVS** backend , and find out the source code  of **GraphDatabaseConfiguration** ;

I tried and get the KCVSConfig use the code following :

```
    PropertiesConfiguration configuration = new PropertiesConfiguration(GRAPH_PROPERTIES);

    ReadConfiguration localConfig = new CommonsConfiguration(configuration);
    BasicConfiguration localBasicConfiguration = new BasicConfiguration(ROOT_NS,localConfig, BasicConfiguration.Restriction.NONE);

    KeyColumnValueStoreManager storeManager = Backend.getStorageManager(localBasicConfiguration);

    KCVSConfiguration KCVSConfig =Backend.getStandaloneGlobalConfiguration(storeManager,localBasicConfiguration);
```

Just using the **KCVSConfiguration** to remove all the index configuration !